# How can I find the record with the max value for a group?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query for a large dataset with many joins and having trouble accomplishing a particular piece without some sort of subquery, which I am trying to avoid.

For an example table with columns ID, Size, Item there may be multiple records with the same ID. I want to return the record per ID which has the largest Size.

```
ID  Size    Item
1   5   a
1   10  b
2   3   c
2   6   d
2   11  e
3   2   f
```

Expected result

```
ID  Size    Item
1   10  b
2   11  e
3   2   f
```

I've tried various group and having approaches without success.

Using a subquery I can do it like this but for a large dataset I'd prefer not to do it this way

```
select id, size, item
from test
where size = (select max(size) from test t2 where id = test.id)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should satisfy your requirements:  *For each id, return only the row with the largest size*

```
SELECT test.id, test.size, test.item
FROM test
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, MAX(size) AS size
    FROM test
    GROUP BY id
) max_size ON max_size.id = test.id AND max_size.size = test.size
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH    T AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID 
                                                ORDER BY Size DESC ) AS RN
               FROM     YourTable
             )
    SELECT  ID ,
            Size ,
            Item
    FROM    T
    WHERE   RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, item, MAX(size)
FROM Test
GROUP BY id, item
```

Assuming `item` is the same for every occurrence of that `id`.

Comment: Item is different which is what makes this more complicated. I have added example data to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, max(size), item
from test
group by id, item
```

Edit: Ah, the data you just added changes this and my above query no longer applies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query(I mean your query) but it's necessary to create composite index (id, size)

Comment: Provided query is optimal for me. So I have added suggestion about the one using.